# How to find the vectors spanning a specific given set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image: The question is given and the answers. But, how to arrive at those answers?]
How to find the vectors spanning a specific given set? The specific set is given in the photo and answers provided. But how those answers are obtained is a mystery to me. A complete solution to this problem would help immensely in my understanding of this topic, so thank you very much if you decide to help.

Comment: This is a new level of asking to do homework. What methods have you used in class already? Notice that the vectors are just reading off coefficients for each scalar vertically. Can you see why this achieves the required solution?

Comment: This isn't homework, I thought that's clear. I want to understand how the answer was obtained. I see what you're saying, but no, I don't understand it yet. Please explain.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^4$, $v_1, \dots v_4$ *span* some subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb R^4$ if every $w \in V$ can be written as a linear combination

$$w:=(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4)=a_1 v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3+a_4 v_4.$$


In components, I will write $v_i=(v_{i1},v_{i2},v_{i3},v_{i4})$ this means that $w_i=\alpha v_{1i}+\beta v_{2i}+\gamma v_{3i}+\delta v_{4i}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u=\begin{pmatrix}-2\alpha+\beta+3\gamma-\delta\\\alpha+2\beta+\gamma+\delta\\-\alpha-5\beta-\gamma+2\delta\\\alpha+5\beta-\gamma-7\delta\end{pmatrix}=\alpha\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\-5\\5\end{pmatrix}+\gamma\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}+\delta\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\2\\-7\end{pmatrix}$$
So any $u\in M$ can be written as a linear combination of $(-2,1,-1,1), (1,2,-5,5), (3,1,-1,1), (-1,1,2,-7)$. These four vectors therefore span $M$.